# Force frozen column row to resize with handsontable

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I have some javascript that changes the content of certain cells in a handsontable grid.

The issue I have found is that when I change the content of one of the cells the frozen column rows don't change accordingly.

Is there a function that can be run to check the sizes of each row and resize accordingly?

I have a Jsfiddle which shows the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/JammyDodger231/145bL7ej/

```
var myData = Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(4, 20);

hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: myData,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    fixedRowsTop: 2,
    fixedColumnsLeft: 2
});

//Hardcoded just to show issue, this isnt where the content would be changed
$('.htCore tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(5)').html("Test <br /><br />");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you should NEVER manually change content or CSS on the table that Handsontable renders for you. It is a stateless table which will get overriden as soon as you make any changes that triggers a change event. Read this answer to get a more detailed description:

[CSS applied on Handsontable grid row on Scroll is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32793418/css-applied-on-handsontable-grid-row-on-scroll-is-not-working-properly)

What you should be doing instead is using the methods that Handsontable supplies to you. In your case, you can use `hot.setDataAtCell(row, col, value)`. You could also directly change `myData` since Handson uses a reference to it. Anything but manually changing the DOM.

Comment: Ah, I had not realized that I had to use the functions from handsontable to alter the content of the table