# Handsontable persistent CSS

Tags: javascript, css, handsontable

according to this question [CSS applied on Handsontable grid row on Scroll is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32793418/css-applied-on-handsontable-grid-row-on-scroll-is-not-working-properly) I'm using a custom renderer to apply styles for my cells (bold, italic, underline, font size, font family).

As is suggested in the answer to the question above, I have a backing array of objects, each one representing each cell in my table with its own attributes so that renderer would know what to render (ie bold: true, italic: false).

However, this seems like a clunky way to do it because when I insert a row/col, I need to reflect this change in the backing array too, so that I can render it again. This seems like too much hassle to me and I can't imagine there's not a simpler way to do it (imagine having a full 100x100 table with custom CSS all over and inserting a col to the beginning).

Example of my code:

```
var myRenderer = function myRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);

    var id = row+","+col;
    var result = $.grep(arr, function(e){ return e.id == id; });
    if (result[0] == undefined) {
        return;
    }
    if (result[0].bold) {
        var cell = $("table tr:eq(" + row + ") td:eq(" + col + ")");
        cell.css("font-weight", "bold");
    }
    ...
}
```

Is there a simpler way to store CSS styles **directly** in the handsontable instance so that I don't have to have a backing array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that CSS classes are persistent in cell metadata. This means that it should be possible to have a class for each style (or create them programmatically in runtime) and just append it to the cell classes.

**style.css**

```
.myBold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**script.js**

```
function addClass(row, col, mClass) {
    // row is row of the cell, col is column of the cell

    var cell = $("table tr:eq(" + row + ") td:eq(" + col + ")");

    // OPTIONAL - remove highlights from cells if you selected them by dragging
    cell.removeClass("area");
    cell.removeClass("highlight");
    cell.removeClass("current");
    // END OPTIONAL

    var classes = cell.attr("class");
    classes += mClass; //"myBold" in this case

    var hotCells = hot.getSettings().cell; //hot is Handsontable instance

    var containsCell = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < hotCells.length; i++) {
        if (hotCells[i].row == row && hotCells[i].col == col) {
            hotCells[i].className = classes;
            containsCell = true;
        }
    }

    if (!containsCell) {
        hotCells.push({row: row, col: col, className: classes});
    }

    hot.updateSettings({
        cell: hotCells
    });
}

function removeClass(row, col, mClass) {
    var cell = $("table tr:eq(" + row + ") td:eq(" + col + ")");

    cell.removeClass(mClass);

    var classes = cell.attr("class");

    var hotCells = hot.getSettings().cell;
    for (var i = 0; i < hotCells.length; i++) {
        if (hotCells[i].row == row && hotCells[i].col == col) {
            hotCells[i].className = classes;
        }
    }

    hot.updateSettings({
        cell: hotCells
    });
}
```

Remember that `hot.updateSettings()` is a slow operation so make sure to do it outside of loops.